# How do I give request parameters for a POST using MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I try to junit the following controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value="actions.htm", params="reqType=delete",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String deletePendingAction(@RequestParam("aPk") Long aPk)
  {
    pendingActionsService.deletePendingAction(aPk);
    return "Deleted";
  }
```

I use params="reqType=delete" and this is I think the reason why junit fails to map to the controller. I tested all other controllers and they work fine without params tag to the controller. My junit config is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfig.class,loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class JUnitTests {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Before
   public void SetupContext()
   {
     this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
   }

   @Test
   public void testController() throws Exception
   {
      this.mockMvc.perform(post("/actions.htm","reqType=delete").param("aPk","2"));
   }
}
```

How do I translate this params tag to the spring mvc junit? Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add param `reqType=delete' to url.

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/actions.htm?reqType=delete")
                .param("aPk", "2")).andReturn().getResponse().getStatus());
```

Comment: that actually worked but I don't understand why this.mockMvc.perform(post("/pendingactions.htm","?reqType=delete") doesn't work..it should still append it to the uri..

Answer (score 0):

In fact the test should be like this, based on your controller:

```java
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.junit.Assert;

final MvcResult result = mockMvc
       .perform(post("/actions.htm")
                     .param("reqType", "delete")
                     .param("aPk", "2"))
       .andExpect(
                status().isOk()
       .andReturn());

final String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
Assert.assertEquals("Deleted", content);
```